# cloning and pushing back to a .git file, not .git directory

Tags: git, push

Alright, I understand that `error: failed to push some refs to` is a common issue in git and that there is a lot of material online about it, but nothing is helping. So let me explain the issue:

I was given a `name.git` file, not a folder. I did:

`git clone name.git name` This generated my `name` directory with the code
I worked on it, have made a series of commits. Nothing left to be committed. (this is all on my local machine, so no one committed in the meanwhile, but...) I still did `git pull`. `Already up to date`. OK then, `git push` and it responds `error: failed to push some refs to`.

Now, I need to make my commits available to other people. I know, I can just rar/zip my `name` directory, but I wanted to actually have a `name.git` file to give back that would include the logs of my commits. Anyone has any idea what is happening?

Comment: Your `name.git` wasn't a resource on the Internet, was it? Are you certain that `name.git` is a local file? What format of file is that? The convention in the git world is often that `name.git` is actually what is known as a **bare repository**, that is to say, a directory that does not also host a **working copy** of the project checked out.

Comment: I was given the file via skype. I am certain that the file is a local file, I made multiple copies of it and multiple clones, as in git clone, of them.

Comment: as in git clone?! show us exact commands you typed

Comment: What OS? Isn't the file kind of an archive transparent to the OS?

Comment: I am on windows 7 using git bash. Exact commands:
1. I copy pasted the file I received name.git to my workspace:
2. cd to_my_workspace
3. git clone name.git name
4. cd name
after some changes introduced
5. git commit -m "my changes"
6. git push
I get error.
I research online, and make sure that I have nothing left to commit and that I am up to date with origin
7. git push
same error

Comment: Tip: edit your "question" to make updates, hopefully in an obvious way. Use a comment to clarify what was updated if it's too subtle.

Comment: --1-- Can you also show more of the error message? I'm kind of anticipating permission errors now. --2-- Can you try doing `cd name.git`, and `ls name.git`? I feel weird for never having seen a single-file of the `name.git` type. I'm totally curious what kind of file it is. Could you ask the person who created it to show us what command(s) were used to create the file?

Comment: I thought it could be permissions issue. Ls -la shows "-rw-r--r--". So, I switched to admin and used git out of git bash, the same error. I switched os to Ubuntu, same permissions, same error. Nothing else is included in the error. I do chmod 755 name.git and that has no effect. I am only left to try that bundle idea. Soon as I get on my machine, I will try that. Will get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand it now.

You probably received a "git bundle", and a git bundle simply doesn't like being pushed-to, apparently.

Taking cues from: http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/tips-and-tricks

*Note - Assume you can use the Linux-esque `touch` command to create a plain empty file*

Create new project:

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
touch hello
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Create bundle:

```
git bundle create ../foo.git master
```

Make use of bundle:

```
cd ..
git clone foo.git foo-clone -b master
cd foo-clone
touch world
git add .
git commit -m "second commit"
```

Try to push to bundle, but fail:

```
git push origin master
```

> error: failed to push some refs to [foo.git]*

* foo.git path is actually expanded out

Therefore, maybe you could also bundle up your repository and ship it back to your upstream.

**Addition** - You could also submit a "[git-format-patch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch)" style of patch upstream, too; it will be far less heavy than a bundle.

Alternatively, you and your team can explore solutions like [GitHub](https://github.com/), [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/), and [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)

*Note - GitLab and BitBucket have options for "local install, total privacy".*

Comment: Thanks a lot starlocke. This was what I have been looking for. There is a minor detail: "git bundle create bundle.git --all" instead of "git bundle create bundle.git master". That's it. Thanks one more time.

Comment: I'll leave it as `master`, since the test/example case only had master and nothing else in it. Opting for `--all` is one of those "with great power comes great responsibility" adult choices we must make in our lives.